# Command to list file and show its timestamp with milliseconds in sftp command

Tags: linux, sftp, ls

Normally in Linux or Unix, I will use following command to list the files's timestamp in milliseconds:

```
ls -la --time-style=full-iso file1.txt
ls -la --time-style=full-iso file2.txt
ls --full-time
```

How if I want to do it in `sftp` command? Does `sftp` command support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to OpenSSH `sftp` command, then there's indeed no support for milliseconds.

As of OpenSSH 8.4, its SFTP implementation supports SFTP version 3 only, which does not support milliseconds. There's no active development in SFTP in OpenSSH, so it's unlikely it changes any time soon.

---

Even if you pick another SFTP client that supports milliseconds, you also must have a support for milliseconds on SFTP server. But majority of SFTP servers are OpenSSH again.